# Sql complicated order clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have table contains State,City,Street etc. And for each street there is 3 adres. First is main, and the others are replacement1,replacement2.

I am ordering result by city and street. result is like below

1. City     Street        AdresType
2. Sincan   Plevne St.    Replacement1
3. Sincan   Plevne St.    Main
4. Sincan   Plevne St.    Replacement2
5. Sincan   Bosna  St.    Replacement2
6. Sincan   Bosna  St.    Replacement1
7. Sincan   Bosna  St.    Main

but I want AdresType goes periodically like below

1. City     Street         AdresType

   2. Sincan   Plevne St.    **Main**
   3. Sincan   Plevne St.    **Replacement1**
   4. Sincan   Plevne St.    **Replacement2**
   5. Sincan   Bosna  St.    **Main**
   6. Sincan   Bosna  St.    **Replacement1**
   7. Sincan   Bosna  St.    **Replacement2**

is it possible.

Comment: "City Street AdresType" - Is this your column name or part of the data? Also, which DBMS are you using>

Comment: Yes they are my columns.  I use sql server and sql management studio

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your three columns are `City`, `Street` and `AdresType`, and sample data for one row is `City = Sincan, Street = Plevne St., AdresType = Main`, you can do as shown below:

```
select City, Street, AdresType
from yourtable
order by City, Street desc, AdresType
```

This will first sort in ascending alphabetical order by `City`, then in descending order by `Street` so that "Plevne St." is shown before "Bosna St.", and finally it sorts by `AdresType` in ascending order so that "Main" is at the top, followed by "Replacement1" and "Replacement2" in that order.